# C# "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative"

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to create a small application that reads in an excel file of postcodes and then automatically checks certain websites for 3G signal coverage. however, this block of code is producing the error mentioned in the topic title.

```
        //Find the input field on the three postcode checker
        int x;
        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            IWebElement input = driver.FindElement(By.Name("postcode"));
            string postcodeInput = (dataGridView1.SelectedCells[x].Value.ToString());
            string returnKey = OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Return;

            input.SendKeys(postcodeInput);
            input.SendKeys(returnKey);

            IWebElement output = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("h5"));
            string postcodeOutput = output.Text;
            dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value = postcodeOutput;

            input.Clear();
        }
        driver.Quit();
```

The line VS highlights is:

```
string postcodeInput = (dataGridView1.SelectedCells[x].Value.ToString());
```

Any one have any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Well debug it. What is the value of `x` when it the error occurs?

Comment: You'll have to add a breakpoint on that line and do some debugging. I'm guessing it has something to do with `(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[x].Value.ToString())` or `dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value`

Answer (score 0):

Don't hardcode 100 in the limit value check of your `for` loop.  Use the actual count from your grid like this:

```
for (x = 0; x < dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count; x++)
```

It may be that your grid's selected cell collection doesn't have what you expect.  But hardcoding a value like this is never a good idea, and is why you are getting an "index was out of range" error.